# In Tableau how to show Dashboard refresh date in Header?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard in Tableau which consists of multiple worksheet, a header and a footer. The header is basically an image and textbox inside a vertical object. I am trying to add the date the dashboard was last refreshed to the header, in the text box. Everywhere I look and someone asks a similar question, every tells them how to add it to a worksheet. I do not want it in my worksheet, I want it in my header. All the worksheets use the same data source and thus have the same refresh datetime. I do not want to add it to every worksheet (clutter) and I do not want to add it to a single worksheet (Confusing did anything else update?). In something like SSRS you might do a Max(Date) from one of the data sources or a NOW() to get the current datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a worksheet that looks like you want and use that as your dashboard “header’ instead.  Could be as simple as one text mark

Comment: Thank Alex, that is what I ended up doing. It to bad Tableau doesn't let you reference different data set more easily.